# HTML table: how to make all rows equal height?

Tags: html, css, html-table, rows

I'm generating a table in HTML. I have a number of rows, whose count is kept in the variable `{{ items|length }}`

How do I make all rows the same height except the header row?

I've tried:

```
<style>
     table.equalDivide th { width:100 / {{ items|length }} %; }
</style>
```

But this doesn't work.

All the rows should have the height of the tallest one (12:00 - 14:00 in the image below).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as simple as I can get it - but it works...

Use Notepad or similar (Notepad++ recommended) to edit your HTML file as follows:
    (NOTE: syntax is crucially important - follow it exactly - especially single or double quotes)

1: Give your table a unique ID: table id="myTable" ...

2: Give your body element an onload function: body onload="resizeTable('myTable');" ...

3: In your head section add this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resizeTable(tableID)
{
var tbl=document.getElementById(tableID), biggestRow=0, rowHeight=0, row=0;
for (row=0; row < tbl.rows.length; row++) {     //find biggest row height
    rowHeight=parseInt(tbl.rows[row].offsetHeight);
    if (rowHeight > biggestRow) {biggestRow=rowHeight;}
}
for (row=0; row < tbl.rows.length; row++) {     //set all rows to biggest row height
    tbl.rows[row].style.height=biggestRow + "px";
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this later :)

Comment: Doing it like this probably causes the table to visibly "jump" from its natural layout to forced equal-height rows. This will happen right after the page loads. May be OK in some cases, and is probably not acceptable in other cases.

Comment: @Jan Żankowski - I agree, needs to be done right after page load. It's not something I've personally ever used - I just answered a question. Do you know of a better way? Flexible design / grid methods may offer a neater solution nowadays, but I've not tried. Tony Duffill

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** I think what you want to occur already happens normally. I created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wk8xr0us/) that shows how a large cell will force other cells in the same row to have its height. I'm curious if something else is happening for you. Sorry if I am misunderstanding you.

---

Just apply a height to all the tr's. If you want the height to be dependent on the number of rows, just change the css rule accordingly.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<th>Title</th>
<tr><td>Foo</td></tr>
<tr><td>Bar</td></tr>
<tr><td>Baz</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
tr {
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but I don't know how much text I will have in each row, and I want to all cells have height of this the bigger one cell

Comment: "this the bigger one cell" Are you saying you want the height of the row to be equal to the lenght of the largest row item? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: It looks like this with your rule. I want all rows the same height, but this height depends of data which I have. And I also don't want affect this first row

Comment: So you want the height to be the same as the largest cell (in your example, the light blue rectangle on the bottom right?

Comment: Only this height 12:00-14:00. Or height blue one from 8:00-10:00

Comment: Oh! You want each row to have the height of the largest cell?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101212/discussion-between-user3797879-and-james-hill).

Answer (score 1):

I know of no way to do this with CSS.

All you can do (I think) is in your onload() function get the biggest row height by iterating through the table rows (table.rows[..].offsetHeight (I hope that's right-if not, try biggest cell height), then set the height of each row in the table to that value.

Comment: Maybe you could tell me something more about it, because I don't using JS here

Comment: I could tell you a lot about it, but if you don't want to use javascript, or don't have time to learn it, this is not the best place to start.

Comment: Sorry, that may have sounded a bit abrupt.

If you really want, I can send you the code, but you'd then be using javascript that you might not fully understand.

Let me know if you're interested.

Comment: I'd be happy to see this solution for further purposes. Because I am planning to learn JS in future. In this project I will left it as it is.

Comment: Fine - let me concentrate and I'll tell you how to do it